# Mapping SQL 2008 datetimeoffset using nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, sql-server-2008

Is there any supported way of mapping datetimeoffset the new datatype in SQL 2008 to the System.DateTimeOffset using nhibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NH 2.1 (or compiling from NHibernate trunk) supports this and more out-of-the-box. [Check it out](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/11/nhibernate-and-ms-sql-server-2008-date-time-datetime2-and-datetimeoffset.aspx)

Comment: Link is broken. That domain doesn't currently exist.

Comment: This was long time ago! NHibernate project is on Github https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming google didn't turn of anything)
You will probably need to create a simple IUserType to handle this, also I am sure that the NH team would gladly accept it as a patch for everyone to benifit.

Ayende has a good post [here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/07/31/Entities-dependencies-best-practices.aspx) on this.  He goes though a couple of options to solve his problem so you might want to start from the bottom of the post (not the comments) and go up.